# Group schemes over valuation rings

Tags: group-schemes

Let $S=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ for a valuation ring $R$ and $G$ a group scheme over $S$. Is $G$ necessarily separated (maybe with some finiteness condition)?

Comment: Have you heard of the valuative criterion of properness ?

Comment: Yes. You mean to refer to the one for separatedness? Does it hold?

Comment: Yeah, I meant separatedness

Comment: @RobertGreen -Still, I'm not sure why it holds...

Comment: See this : http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06E7 it may inspire you ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think k[x] is a valuation ring.

Comment: Never said it was. ;-) Gave you link for inspiration, not to answer.

Comment: General fact : let $S$ be a scheme and $G$ be a group scheme over $S$, then $G$ is separated over $S$ if and only if the identity morphism $e : S \to G$ is a closed immersion. Is this the case if $S = \textrm{Spec}(V)$ with $V$ a valuation ring which is not a field ?

Comment: I am aware of these facts, but still couldn't find a counter example or proof...

Comment: Have you seen the exemple of the affine line with origin over the affine line over a field, in the link I gave you ? Do you think you could produce the same example when replacing $k[T]$ by a dvr for instance ?